# Can I deserialize the different users like student and admin in passport.js?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

In passport js authentication when the deserialize the user I have the following doubt?

Can I use different Login tables to fetch the user ?(depends on they are admin or student like that)
But I was try to implement it by using if statement that was won't work it which mean cannot fetch from db. What I am doing that any help !

Comment: use permission rather than table. and u can use. just have to make 2 calls

Answer (score 0):

Using LocalStrategy u can use it. Here you have to make two different calls to check.

**Sample:**

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    async.parallel([
      function(cb){
        User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
          if (err) { return done(err); }
          if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
          if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
          return cb(null, user);
        });
      },
      function(cb){
        Admin.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
          if (err) { return done(err); }
          if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
          if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
          return cb(null, user);
        });
      }
    ], ([res1, res2]) => {
      // on result 
      done(null, res1)
      // OR
      done(null, res1)
    })

  }
));
```